# Ionic 3 Swiping Slides

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an application with ionic v3 and have an ionic-slides component. At the moment the slides scroll horizontally, but they lock into position when scrolling, but I would like it to be a free scroll where the slides do not lock.

I have tried setting the freeMode attribute in options to true, but that doesn't seem to work. On the ionic documentation, there seems to be no freeMode attribute.

Is there any way I could achieve free swiping slides in ionic?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-swipe-demo-awrxk2?file=app/app.html)

go through example that contain full code

```
<ion-card #mycards1 swing-card *ngFor="let c of cards">
        <img *ngIf="c.picture" [src]="c.picture.large">
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
                <h2>{{ c.name.first }} {{ c.name.last}}</h2>
                <p>{{ c.email }}</p>
            </ion-card-title>

            From: {{ c.location.city }}, {{ c.location.postcode }}<br> Phone: {{ c.phone }}
        </ion-card-content>

        <ion-row *ngIf="c.name">
            <ion-col>
                <button ion-button clear small icon-left color="primary" (click)="voteUp(true)">
        <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
        Yes
      </button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
                <button ion-button clear small icon-left color="primary" (click)="voteUp(false)">
        <ion-icon name="thumbs-down"></ion-icon>
        No
      </button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use ion-slides .Please go through ionic documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/slides/Slides/

Please refer the sample code

```
<ion-slides pager="false" slidesPerView="1" shouldLockSwipes="1">
            <ion-slide *ngFor="let promocode of promocodedata">
                <ion-card  >
                    <ion-card-header>
                        {{promocode.code}}
                    </ion-card-header>
                    <ion-card-content>
                    Upto <br>
                    <p>{{promocode.rate}}% Off</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 9px;">{{promocode.description}}</p>
                    </ion-card-content>
                  </ion-card>
            </ion-slide>

         </ion-slides>
```

Comment: I get that "shouldLockSwipes" isn't a known proper of ion-slides. Which property allows for freemode swiping?